# Activating a tooltip that uses a common div as the tip... (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I've looked around a bit, but can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

What I want to do:
I have a div that has content in it, including other elements. It is to remain hidden on the page, but I want to use it as the tooltip of three different elements **without duplicating the toolip div.**

So, for example, I have a div and 3 images:

```
<div id='tooltip_div'>This is <b>a tooltip</b> to be used for the three images</div>
<img src='1.jpg' />
<img src='2.jpg' />
<img src='3.jpg' />
```

I want to attach a tooltip to each of those images with the content of the `#tooltip_div` div. I've looked at [this](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html) but it seems that is expects the tooltip to come immediately after the target element. This would require duplicating the tooltip div for however many target elements I want to associate it with (so, I would have to have that div three times, once after each image).

It would be great if I could sort of do `$('img').tooltip('#tooltip_div')`, basically tell the plugin which element to use for the tooltip.

If anyone can help, that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another tooltip plugin that I've used that does support this.

[jQuery Tools Tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html)

Notice the `tip` option which you can specify a single tooltip element.

Comment: That's the same plugin as I linked... however, I didn't know about the `tip` option, I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: I decided to go with this answer. I have run into another problem with it tho lol: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769317/having-trouble-with-jquery-tooltips

Answer (score 2):

Try [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/). It's great plugin and easy to activate

```
$(".tip").tipsy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [TipTip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin). You add a `title` attribute to the things you want to have a tooltip, and then add the class 'tip', meaning you can then do:

```
$(".tip").tipTip();
```

You can also customise the contents of the resulting tooltip to be whatever you want, using the `content()` method. Possibly pull in your content from your hidden div using `.content($("#tooltip_div").html())`;

Comment: Haven't really looked at TipTip, but I can tell you right now things that need to be in the `title` attribute **will not work**. The actual tooltip div is much more complicated than the example, having more HTML elements and images and it's own CSS. It wouldn't be proper or even possible putting that in the title attribute. Correct me if I'm wrong tho =)

Comment: Updated to include an example with complex html.

Comment: Thanks for updating it to clarify. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Tipsy is even better : http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/.
Activate HTML, set a static mssage (your div) and you're done.

Give your images a class, say `class="images"`.

Then you just type :
`$(".images").tipsy({html: true, fallback: "*your div, your content, whatever*});`

Comment: Could you go into more detail as to setting a static tip? I've looked it over and can't figure it out. I've been trying to use the jQuery Tools, but they seem to be buggy, and so I'm trying Tipsy now.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the clarification. In the end I decided to go with Qtip - it seems like it's got all the features  would need (my application is a bit more than just a shared hidden div)